# jQuery deferred: why is this failed request resolving?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, jquery-deferred

I have two AJAX deferreds which, when both succeed, should result in a success message. Otherwise, if either fails, the error message should show. Reduced code:

```
var reqs = $.map(['file', 'db'], function(mode) {
    $.get(wspath(desyn.repo_id, 'revert', { mode: mode, path: path, version: ver }))
});

$.when(reqs[0], reqs[1]).then(
    function() { alert('success'); },
    function() { alert('error'); }
);
```

For debugging purposes, I force the first request to fail - on the server I'm throwing an internal 500 error. This is borne out in the network console. However, the success callback is executed nonetheless, not the fail callback.

As I understand it (and as described in the final example on the [jQuery docs page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)), passing two functions to `then()` means the first is the success callback and the latter the fail callback. So what's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do `return $.get(...` to actually have the deferred objects in the array

Comment: Oh god... did I really just do that? Face palm x 1,000,000. Thanks for pointing out my lac of attention.